# Is there a way to hide the footer of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a table view that is inside a viewcontroller, the tableview resizes according to the dynamic cells, sometimes there are only 1 rows, sometimes more, the problem is that the footer of the tableview occupies a lot of space, i want the footer to hide, i tries using the delegate method viewForFooterInSection, and also setting the footer height to 0 in viewdidload method, and to 1.0 in heightForFooterInSection, and the footer is still showing, here is a photo of the tableview, i made the footer background black to check where is it

[image]
this is the code i use in viewdidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let notificationName = Notification.Name(rawValue: "ErrorGettingReportDetail")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.mostrarErrorDetalle), name: notificationName, object: nil)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    /*self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.backView.layer.masksToBounds = true*/

    self.backScrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.backScrollView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.commentTextView.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissCommentsPopUp")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.tagsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.commentTextView.autocorrectionType = .no

    self.tagsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
    self.tagsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and this is the code i use for the tableview:

```
//MARK: -TagsTableView
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(self.reporte != nil){
        if((self.reporte?.atributosInfo?.count)! > 0){
            return (self.reporte?.atributosInfo?.count)!
        }else{
            //self.tagsTableView.isHidden = true
            return 0
        }
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(KRProgressHUD.isVisible){
        KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
    if(self.reporte != nil){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "atributoCell") as! AtributoTableViewCell
        let atributosInfo = self.reporte?.atributosInfo![indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCellWith(atributoInfo: atributosInfo!)
        cell.atributo = atributosInfo
        print(indexPath.row)
        let height = cell.frame.height
        self.tagsTableViewHeight.constant += height
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        //self.tagsTableViewHeight.constant -= cell.frame.height
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

//MARK END
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you setting the table view's footer? Are you sure there is a footer? Perhaps you simply made the table view taller than its cells.

Comment: i made the tableview background in color black, so when i enter a screen which only shows 1 cell, the black bottom rectangle shows, also in cell for row the table view grows according to the cells, as you can see in the code, the tableview height is fixated to 138, but when there are more cells the tableview adds up the cell height to its own height

Answer (score 3):

please use this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Comment: Above generally works fine, however in some cases (not yet determined when), `tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true` needs to be added together with `return .leastNonzeroMagnitude`. Otherwise the height of the footer will be correctly reduced to 0, but the footer text will be partially visible across the section above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewDidLoad:

```
tagsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

There is a section footer and a tableView footer.